# Saving MediaPlayer instance inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using the android `ViewPager` and in it I have 3 `Fragments`. I am also implementing the **adapter of this ViewPager** with the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, so that using the `onSaveInstanceState` is effective. In my 3rd Fragment since I am working with a `MediaPlayer`, saving its instance wasn't quite flexible.

For e.g. in my other two fragments, only saving the data related with the layout was enough. But with the MediaPlayer, the layout information was not enough as the media was loaded from the start. It didn't continue to play from where the user left. Could someone please suggest me a way to implement this.